# UINavigationController "back button" custom text?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

The "back button" of a `UINavigationController` by default shows the title of the last view in the stack. Is there a way to have custom text in the back button instead?

Comment: This work for me `self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Custom text";`

Answer (score 345, accepted):

From [this link](http://blog.evandavey.com/2008/12/how-to-change-text-on-back-button-in-uinavigationbar-uinavigationcontroller.html):

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom Title"
            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
           target:nil
           action:nil];
```

As Tyler said in the comments:

> *don't do this in the visible view controller, but in the view
>   controller that you'd see if you hit the back button*

Comment: You should `release` the `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: Also note, you need to do this in the view controller one level up the stack.  In other words, don't do this in the visible view controller, but in the view controller that you'd see if you hit the back button.

Comment: Thank you so much Tyler. Your comment saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Just to clarify Tyler's comment because I did not understand this at first: Setting the backBarButtonItem in a view controllers navigationItem is setting the button that will show to get BACK to this view controller. Also note that although there is no button style for the arrow button this button will get the arrow style anyway. I have used UIBarButtonItemStylePlain and still get the arrow button style.

Comment: Another woe I encountered if it can help anyone: You need all view controllers in the stack to implement some title or navigation item. Otherwise there are holes in the navigation item list, and it starts messing up...

Comment: I tried to set title to this item without initializing it - didn't work. This works and custom appearence also works even though you init with style Bordered.

Comment: It doesn't work. I set that to Back it still shows the title of the previous viewController.

Comment: Suggestion: Rather than assume the style, pass the currently set style. In this answer's code, replace `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` with a call to the property `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.style`. Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarButtonItem/style

Comment: Note that under ARC you must leave out the autorelease call. so you have self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom Title"
            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
           target:nil
           action:nil];

Comment: **Swift Code**:  

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: nil, action: nil)`

Comment: Also note this: "If the title of your back button is too long to fit in the available space on the navigation bar, the navigation bar may substitute the string “Back” in place of the button’s original title." [From the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html)

Comment: What about custom color?

Comment: Thanks Zaheer for the Swift version. I got a warning about "UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered" being deprecated, so I replaced that with "UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain"

Comment: Can this same technique be used to override the action of the "back" button? For example, if I wanted to call `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` instead of simply going back by one ViewController?

Comment: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered has been deprecated in iOS 8.0. Use UIBarButtonItemStylePlain in iOS 7.0 and later.

Comment: This works very well, but it makes no logical sense at all.  Why would I want to add a back button to SELF (the previous controller) as opposed to viewDidLoad event of the screen that needs the button....

Answer (score 44):

You can set the text in the Interface Builder:

Select the navigation item of the ViewController that the back button would return to:

[image]

In the utilities panel attribute inspector, enter your label for the Back Button:

[image]

I would prefer this approach over setting the title in code as in the accepted answer.

> Also note, you need to do this in the view controller one level up the
>   stack. In other words, don't do this in the visible view controller,
>   but in the view controller that you'd see if you hit the back button.
>   **--Tyler**

Comment: This is the best answer I found so far.

Comment: To be clear, this needs to be set on the view controller's Navigation Item, not on the view controller's attributes inspector itself.

Comment: This is the best answer I found.

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: As of Xcode 6.1.1, and running in iOS 7, it seems your original previous view title will STILL override whatever back button title you set here. If the previous view's title contains more than the limit of 11 chars, then the next view's back button will simply say "Back". There's no way around it except to create a new nav bar item from scratch as shown in the top-voted answer here.

Comment: This should be way higher on this thread. Worked like a charm and keeps the code clean

Answer (score 22):

I use this:

```
// In the current view controller, not the one that is one level up in the stack
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"Custom text";
}
```

Comment: This almost works for me, but when I click the back button, the text changes back to the title of the parent for the duration of the animation :-(

Comment: This changes the Back button title of the controller up in the stack. It does not change the Back button title of the currently displayed controller. 

Even worse: it changes the title of the controller previous to the previous controller!

Comment: As noted by other commenters, this method is a little untenable. I wouldn't recommend doing this as it's not really how the API intends you to use it. You could be setting yourself up for difficult bugs in the future!

Answer (score 11):

I found a handy solution to this by simply setting the title of the controller before pushing another controller onto the stack, like this:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Replacement Title";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newCtrl animated:YES];
```

Then, make sure to set the original title in `viewWillAppear`, like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  ...
  self.navigationItem.title = @"Original Title";
  ...
}
```

This works because the default behavior of `UINavigationController` when constructing the back button during a push operation is to use the title from the previous controller.

Comment: The problem with this is the title changes on the old view as it animates out and looks a bit naff. None of the given solutions here seem to work as you'd like :-(

Comment: This is perfect in my situation because I don't show the NavBar on the previous screen and I just want to remove the titleLabel from the back button on the new screen and have just the iOS7 chevron arrow. I can therefore just set an empty NSString literal for the title.

Comment: pushing view controller raise the exception when tap on back

Answer (score 7):

The title of the back button defaults to the previous view's title so a quick trick I use is to place the following code on the previous view's .m file.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // Set title
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Original Title";
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    // Set title
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Back";
}
```

Comment: This works pretty well for many cases and it's pretty simple... only observation is that overriding either of these methods requires that the super's implementation be called at some point in the new method.

Comment: With this method, one will notice the title of the parent view being changed to 'Back' before the push animation happens. (And, sorta sucks, that if you move this to the viewDidDisappear method, you'll see the switch happening after the push..)

Comment: I love this method but the problem I face with this is that the "Original Title" gets set alright but it comes with an ellipsis if it is longer than "Back" which must be because, since the view is not yet in the view hierarchy, it does not relayout the title view. The problem described by @JamesBoutcher above is unnoticeable for me due to the fast initial speed of the animation. In fact, I just realized that the problem I face is especially noticeable due to slow ending animation which is when this problem is prominent.

Comment: While the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441699/uinavigationcontroller-back-button-custom-text/1441718#1441718 feels like more customization than necessary, it is the documented way and more importantly seems to be more aligned to our intent.

Answer (score 6):

in your init method, add the following code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    if(self = [super init]) {

        //...

        UIBarButtonItem *customBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                            target:self 
                                            action:@selector(goBack)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBackButton;
        [customBackButton release];

        //...
    }
    return self;
}
```

then add a simple method, to allow viewcontroller dismissing:

```
-(void)goBack {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code in viewDidLoad or loadView

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Custom text";
```

I tested it in iPhone and iPad with iOS 9

Comment: Should be self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Custom Text"

Comment: only difference I needed was the optional chaining on the `navigationController` and `topItem` properties, e.g.: `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Custom Text"`

Answer (score 2):

Adding to rein's answer. Note from Apple's docs that the declaration of **backBarButtonItem** is this:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem
```

Therefore, rein's answer will leak memory because the synthesized setter will `retain` the instance you pass it, which is never released explicitly. You can remedy this by using `autorelease`

```
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = 
      [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom Title" 
         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
         target:nil
         action:nil] autorelease];  //<-- autoreleased
```

Or you could point a variable at the instance so you can explicitly release it later:

```
UIBarButtonItem* item = ...
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item;
[item release];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note these days, with ARC, you don't need to worry about the autorelease (and indeed the compiler will error if you try to autorelease in an ARC-enabled project)

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
  self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
  [backButton release];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered something interesting.
If you subclass the `UINavigationController` and override the `pushViewController:animated:` method and do something like this: (bear in mind that I'm using ARC)

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
 initWithTitle: @"Back" 
 style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
 target: nil action: nil];

viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;

[super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
```

Then for all `ViewControllers` that are pushed with your navigation controller will have the "Back" button in them automatically. If you want to change the text for certain view controllers you can try and maybe cast the viewcontroller to a certain class or your own custom protocol (which your viewcontroller inherits from which could have a method like `backButtonText` or something silly like that) which can give you certain information on the viewcontroller that's coming in sothat you can customize the back button text for it. Now the back button text is taken care of in a place which should hold the responsibility solely. I have to admit that creating a new button to change the text sucks, but oh well.

Can anyone think of a reason why not to do it like this? Atleast you don't have to fiddle with viewcontroller titles or have to remember to create a new back button before pushing the viewcontroller on the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Aubrey's suggestion, you can do this in the child view controller:

create two variables for storing the old values of the parent's navigationItem.title and the parent's navigationItem

```
UINavigationItem* oldItem;
NSString* oldTitle;
```

in `viewDidLoad`, add the following:

```
oldItem = self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem;  
oldTitle = oldItem.title;  
[oldItem setTitle: @"Back"];
```

in `viewWillDisappear`, add the following:

```
[oldItem setTitle: oldTitle];  
oldTitle = nil;  // do this if you have retained oldTitle
oldItem = nil;   // do this if you have retained oldItem
```

It's not perfect. You will see the the title of the parent view change as the new controller is animated in. BUT this does achieve the goal of custom labeling the back button and keeping it shaped like a standard back button.

Answer (score 0):

rein's answer works well.

Note that if you push more than one view controller, the changed back button title will appear for each of them, which may not be what you want.

In that case, you'll need to create the custom UIBarButtonItem each time you push a view controller.

Also, make sure you do it *before* pushing the view controller, otherwise you will get a screen hiccup as the title changes.

Answer (score 0):

Put this into you `viewDidLoad`, hope it will result into what you are looking for

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" 
style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
[backBarButtonItem release];
```

Answer (score 0):

if You want to set title in ARRIVING controller (sometimes more logic..)
in swift 3 do:

```
func setBackButtonNavBar(title: String, delay: Double){

    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: { () -> Void in

        if let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar{
            navBar.backItem?.title = title
        }
    })

}
```

in upcoming controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setBackButtonNavBar(title: "back", delay: 0.3)
}
```

usually I put self.setBackButtonNavBar in a controller extension.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and the answers' kind of out updated!

The easy way is to do this in parent ViewController:

i.e the one that takes you to next view controller.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Custom text here", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

Doing this in code remove the back button style of the `UINavigationConroller`. If you add a Navigation Item in each of yours views, you can set the title of the back botton in the `StoryBoard`.