# Navigation Controller back button

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller

How can I create  a back button of a navigation controller programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441699/uinavigationcontroller-back-button-custom-text

Comment: This method has been deprecated in iOS 8 :/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In `-(void)loadView` or similar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backPressed:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn;
[btn release];

-(void)backPressed: (id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES]; // or popToRoot... if required.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It was my mistake, I had 
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES; in 1 method of my code, I didn't realize it and so finally wrote in a question. Agreed,I should I have done some more research on my code ..