# Can't change back button title but I can hide it

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm developing an **iPhone** application with **latest SDK** and **XCode 4.2**

I use a UINavigationController, and to show a new ViewController I do this on AppDelegate.m:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        }
        self.viewController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"MAIN", nil);

        navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
        navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

        self.window.rootViewController = navController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }

    - (void) openDocumentation
    {
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            docViewController = [[DocumentationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DocumentationViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            docViewController = [[DocumentationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DocumentationViewControllerr_iPad" bundle:nil];
        }
        docViewController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"DOCUMENTATION", nil);
self.viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";
        [navController pushViewController:docViewController animated:YES];
    }
```

On `DocumentationViewController.m` I do this:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
}
```

But it doesn't change back button title.

I move that code to viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

}
```

But still doesn't work.

And this doesn't work either:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";
}
```

But if I do this, to test if I can't access back button:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}
```

It works!! And hides back button.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22):

The back button title shown by a `UINavigationViewController` doesn't depend on the `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title` of the topmost view controller in the stack. It depends on the *second topmost* view controller's value of `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title`.

So you need to set `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title` for whatever view controller is showing when you push your `DocumentViewController`.

Comment: Ok, and now: How can I change it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand you. I have added this line of code at the end of AppDelegate openDocumentation method: `navController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";`. But, it still doesn't show Back text.

Comment: AppDelegate push 'ViewController'. On 'ViewController' I click on a button that calls AppDelegate openDocument method. This method push 'DocumentViewController'.

Comment: So you need to set the `navigationItem.backBarButtonitem.title` for 'ViewController'

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't work. I have updated my question with new code but your answer doesn't work.

Comment: When do you push ViewController onto the navigation view controller? I don't see you doing that in your code. Like I've said before, the navigation bar's back button title is based on the `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title` of the **second from top** view controller in the navigation stack.

Comment: I pust viewController in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Then, when user clicks on document button in viewController I call AppDelegate openDocumentation. In this method I set `self.viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";`

Comment: Try `self.viewController.navigationItem.title = @"Back";` instead

Comment: Seriously? No. You have `self.viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";` I said `self.viewController.navigationItem.title = @"Back";`

Comment: On DocumentationViewController viewWillAppear: backBarButtonItem is nil. I do `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;` and then I don't see back. Your previous comment changes viewController title, and I don't want to do that.

Comment: Fine, then set `self.viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhateverYouWantYourTitleTobe" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

Comment: Yuji's got it correct here. A [link to a related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441699/uinavigationcontroller-back-button-custom-text/1441718#1441718) may help — the solution you've linked to is… to quote the article, crappy. Set the `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` property (a `UIBarButtonItem`) on the controller doing the stack-pushing.

Comment: this may help as well.

Answer (score 2):

When you set the backBarButtonItem title of a UIViewController, you are actually setting the title for the back button if this UIViewController is the second controller in the  UINavigationController stack.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Custom Title";
```

So, if the above view controller is already in the nav controller and subsequently pushes a child view controller into the nav controller, the back button title will be "Custom Title".

Answer (score 0):

Just add in the Storyboard or Nib file your custom button (this will replace the navigation button) and add a back action for it:

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

For me it allows to customize my back button.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this with just one trick:

Override UINavigationBar class and add this line of code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    self.backItem.title = @"";
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Then initialize your UINavigationController with this custom UINavigationBar class.. etc.

`UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CBCNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil]`

Hope this helps