# How do I change the location of the back button on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

You see I am making a completely custom navigation bar and when i create the back button it doesn't stay in the right place as you can see below the code.

here is my code for the app

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if(self.navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1) {
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    
    [backButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapBackButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 44.0f, 45.0f);
    UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
}
```

}

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can just modify contentEdgeInsets to make the position of the button.

Something like this:

> [backButton setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0)];

Come from [UIButton Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

**contentEdgeInsets**

The inset or outset margins for the rectangle surrounding all of the button’s content.

> @property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets contentEdgeInsets

DiscussionUse this property to resize and reposition the effective drawing rectangle for the button content. The content comprises the button image and button title. You can specify a different value for each of the four insets (top, left, bottom, right). A positive value shrinks, or insets, that edge—moving it closer to the center of the button. A negative value expands, or outsets, that edge. Use the UIEdgeInsetsMake function to construct a value for this property. The default value is UIEdgeInsetsZero.

Answer (score 3):

You can render a larger image with some spacing on the left.

```
UIImage *origImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button-thin-hamburger.png"];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(origImage.size.width + 10, origImage.size.height), NO, 0.0);
[origImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(10, 0, origImage.size.width, origImage.size.height)];
UIImage *buttonImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                              target:nil
                                                              action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:buttonImage];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:buttonImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't change, you have to hide it.

Look at this page posted here:

http://rafaelsteil.com/2011/07/23/crappy-ios-apis-uinavigationcontroller/

[Can't change back button title but I can hide it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276002/cant-change-back-button-title-but-i-can-hide-it)

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to summarize the linked material here. Otherwise, the answer is at risk of losing its usefulness due to link rot.

Comment: No i know how to remove the title of the back button just change the location. Is it possible with a cgrect

Answer (score 0):

you need to hide NavigationBar first...

```
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

then  create Custom UIButton..

```
    UIButton *btn1=[UIButton  buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 60, 40)];// Frame u want

    [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BT_ipad_P_backbward@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(Click_backward:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn1.tintColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
    [self.view addSubview:btn1];
```

Comment: Hi friend  i have added four navigation button using array .. its working fine but back indicator button hidded.how to rectify this.